# SQL MAX and MIN in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a problem to get the max and the min value, I want the result to be XXL and XXS

```
  SELECT MAX(tblSizeXL.SizeXLName) AS maxSize, 
         MIN(tblSizeXL.SizeXLName) AS minSize    
    FROM Product 
    JOIN tblSizeXL ON Product.SizeXLID = tblSizeXL.SizeXLID
   WHERE (Product.GroupID = @GroupID)
GROUP BY tblSizeXL.SizeXLID
ORDER BY tblSizeXL.SizeXLID DESC
```

### tblSize

```
SizeXLID     SizeXLName
-----------------------
1            XXS
2            XS
3            S
4            M
5            L
6            XL
7            XXL
8            XXXL
```

Comment: What RDBMS?  Also, wouldn't the max size be XXXL?  And is tblSizeXL the same as tblSize?

Comment: Use MAX/MIN on the .SizeXLID rather than SizeXLName

Comment: Yes its SQL-server, if I have max SizeXLID how do I get the name as result instead of the MAX number.

Comment: Correct XXXL is what I expect as a MAX result, sorry.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that SizeXLID will always order the sizes in the correct order? For example, you'd never add another row to tblSize at a later time for (9, 'XXXS')?

Comment: hmm maybe its better to add XXXXXXS from the begining, that dosent bother to much, thanks

Comment: @Nicklas, it might be better to add a size_order column to tblSizeXL and select MAX and MIN of size_order, rather than relying on the ID column always being in the correct order. That way, you can add new sizes out of sort sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to do an inner queries to get the data you're looking for:

```
SELECT max.SizeXLName as maxSize, min.SizeXLName as minSize
  FROM 
  (SELECT MAX(tblSizeXL.SizeXLID) as MaxSizeXLID, MIN(tblSizeXL.SizeXLID) as MinSizeXLID
     FROM Product
     JOIN tblSizeXL ON Product.SizeXLID = tblSizeXL.SizeXLID
    WHERE Product..GroupID = @GroupID) base
  JOIN tblSizeXL max ON max.SizeXLID = base.MaxSizeXLID
  JOIN tblSizeXL min on min.SizeXLID = base.MinSizeXLID
```

Comment: Looks better, but the result is wrong, I get XXXL and XS, so its almost :)

Comment: My fault, there is an XXS but there was no Product that had that size. Great thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the group by clause and your query should be fine.

Comment: Then I get this: Column "tblSizeXL.SizeXLID" is invalid in the ORDER Y clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If I understood your question, you expect the result to be a single row. In that case you don't need the 'order by' clause